# PowerShell session has terminated upon loading a script with functions

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

Powershell extention crashes as soon as a script with functions is loaded

It was working fine, until I installed Visual studio community to make WPF projects for a PowerShell GUI
After installation the Powershell extention started crashing. 
Now all file that contain a function, crash the Powershell extention.
This happens within a few seconds of opening the file.
When I comment out the function and restart the Powershell extention, it works and I can debug.

I re-installed VS code and the extention for powershell, but so far no luck.
I simplified the issue to :

```
\#function getservice(){

get-service

\#}
```

The above works fine, but as soon as I take the comments away, it crashes.
It crashes as soon as I move to the tab with the script containing functions

extention host log:

> ````
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'command' of undefined    at resolveFunc
> (C:\Users\sce44459\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-1.12.0\out\src\session.js:254:39)  
> [2019-04-09 14:24:21.006] [exthost] [error] [ms-vscode.powershell]
> provider FAILED  
> [2019-04-09 14:24:21.006] [exthost] [error] TypeError:
> Cannot read property 'command' of undefined```
> ````

extention log:

> ````
> 9.4.2019 14:18:46 [NORMAL] - Path specified by 'powerShellExePath' setting - '' - not found, reverting to default PowerShell path.  
> 9.4.2019 14:18:46 [NORMAL] - Language server starting --  
> 9.4.2019 14:18:46 [NORMAL] -     exe: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe  
> 9.4.2019 14:18:46 [NORMAL] -     args: C:\Users\sce44459\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell- 
>  1.12.0\modules\PowerShellEditorServices\Start-EditorServices.ps1
> -HostName 'Visual Studio Code Host' -HostProfileId 'Microsoft.VSCode' -HostVersion '1.12.0' -AdditionalModules @('PowerShellEditorServices.VSCode') -BundledModulesPath
> 'C:\Users\sce44459\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-1.12.0\modules'
> -EnableConsoleRepl -LogLevel 'Normal' -LogPath 'C:\Users\sce44459\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-1.12.0\logs\1554812326-d490a1a0-df66-47c6-a741-74dc46a8873b1554810449036\EditorServices.log' -SessionDetailsPath 'C:\Users\sce44459\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-1.12.0\sessions\PSES-VSCode-5164-189789'
> -FeatureFlags @()  
> 9.4.2019 14:18:47 [NORMAL] - powershell.exe started, pid: 6372  
> 9.4.2019 14:18:50 [NORMAL] - Language server started.  
> 9.4.2019 14:18:50 [NORMAL] - {"languageServiceTransport":"NamedPipe","languageServicePipeName":"\\\\.\\pipe\\PSES_gbzaczkk.xnh","debugServiceTransport":"NamedPipe","status":"started","debugServicePipeName":"\\\\.\\pipe\\PSES_3w4pqudu.4xm"}  
> 9.4.2019 14:18:50 [NORMAL] - Connecting to language service on pipe \\.\pipe\PSES_gbzaczkk.xnh...  
> 9.4.2019 14:18:50 [NORMAL] - Language service connected.  
> 9.4.2019 14:18:57 [NORMAL] - powershell.exe terminated or terminal UI was closed```
> ````

```
Windows 2012

Version: 1.33.0 (system setup)
Commit: `0dd516dd412d42323fc3464531b1c715d51c4c1a`
Date: 2019-04-04T15:14:28.026Z
Electron: 3.1.6
Chrome: 66.0.3359.181
Node.js: 10.2.0
V8: 6.6.346.32
OS: Windows_NT x64 6.3.9600
```

I was not able to find more in the event logs.
Would anyone have an idea what could cause this or what information could help to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

I Was having the same issues connecting to a remote session with VS Code, was getting the same output from VS Code. I was able to work around this issue by uninstalling and then re-installing the PowerShell Extension. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have finally cracked it. 
Re-install did not work (after re-install I noticed all my modules were still there). I now uninstalled all modules (powershell,git history, git project manager , git lens).
Then I un-installed VS code-> reboot-> re-install-> Reinstall Powershell module.
Now it works.

I hope it helps someone else, and thank you all that took the time to have a look, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my fix for it:

1. Reopen VSCode as Admin.
2. If/When prompted to update PackageManager, select Yes, or run this command in a Powershell Terminal inside VSCode (update the version accordingly):

   powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command 'Install-Module -Name PackageManagement -Force -MinimumVersion 1.4.6 -Scope CurrentUser -AllowClobber'
3. Place a breakpoint on the ps1 file and press F5 or Run > Start Debugging (and you'll notice that its running under Powershell Integrated Console not the Windows Powershell as per https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/2897#issuecomment-677963284)